# estimation in C

Tags: c, function

I tried to write a C program to estimate the value of Pi. The compiler, provides a number of errors. What is wrong?

Comment: you can't see them just from the code?

Comment: In the absence of a **strong** reason otherwise, use `double` for "real" values (`float` is faster is not true; `float` is smaller is a very weak reason).

Comment: What compiler are you using? My `gcc` doesn't even find `"randRange.h"`...

Comment: `randRange.h` is a header file that I created.

Comment: Show your header file... it relates to the errors.

Comment: Your function declarations are pointless, since they always immediately precede the function definition. You can safely remove them.

Answer (score 1):

1 Change code from (@Andrew Medico)

```
// void mcPiMultExp(NMEASURES, rev[], NPOINTS);
mcPiMultExp(NMEASURES, rev, NPOINTS);
```

2 As @francis says `res` is not defined.

```
// avg = mean(res, NMEASURES);
// Suggest
avg = mean(v, size);
```

3 `mcPiSingleExp()`, which is call many times, repeatedly performs

```
 srand(time(NULL));
```

The likely should be called only once in the program's run.  Move it to `main()`.

Otherwise since programs are fast and `time()` returns the same value or two, code is initializing the random number generator over and over to the same value.

Comment: @Andrew Medico True.  Post amended.

Answer (score 0):

Read the messages given by compiler !
There are two errors :

- `res` is not defined in `stdDev()`...you want to use the function with `v` as argument.
- One line in `main` : you pasted the function decalaration and forgot to remove the return type and brakets.

Here is a code that should work :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
//#include "randRange.h"
#define RADIUS 1.f
#define MINR -1.f
#define MAXR 1.f
#define NPOINTS 1000
#define NMEASURES 5000
float mcPiSingleExp(int);
float mcPiSingleExp(int n){
    int i,
    countIn = 0;
    float x,y;      
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        x = 2.0*rand()/(double)RAND_MAX-1;
        y = 2.0*rand()/(double)RAND_MAX-1;
        if(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2) <= pow(RADIUS,2))
            countIn++;
    }
    return pow((MAXR-MINR),2) * (float)countIn / (double)n;
}

void mcPiMultExp(int, float [], int);

void mcPiMultExp(int k, float res[], int n){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
        res[i] = mcPiSingleExp(n);
}

float mean(float [], int);
float mean(float v[], int size){
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum += v[i];
    }
    return sum/(double)size;
}

float stdDev(float [], int);
float stdDev(float v[], int size){
    int i;
    float avg, std_dev = 0;
    avg = mean(v,NMEASURES);//mean(res,NMEASURES)
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std_dev += (v[i]-avg)*(v[i]-avg);
    return sqrt(std_dev/size);           
}

int main(){
    float pi, deviation, rev[NMEASURES];
    mcPiMultExp(NMEASURES, rev, NPOINTS);//remove void and []
    pi = mean(rev, NMEASURES);
    deviation = stdDev(rev, NMEASURES);
    printf("\nMean pi = %f\nStandard Deviation = %f\n",pi,deviation);
    return 0;
}
```

The central limit theorem tells you that estimating pi as a probability to fall into the unit disk knowing that you are in the -1;1 square is not going to be very efficient...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Bye,